# specifying what data to return from a REST query

Tags: rest

what is the preferred way to specify what columns to return for a resource?

a resource is a noun, so when I say, `GET employees`, I can specify query parameters to get a limited set of employees. But what about the info on each employee? If the employees table has 12 columns, but I want only three, what is the best way to specify them? Or, do I treat them as different resources?

```
GET employees(all columns)
GET employees(name, age)
GET employees(id, salary)
```

I have seen suggestions such as (*note to overzealous editors: fictitious example below, please don't obfuscate it with markdown syntax*)

```
http://path/to/server/employees/?q=queryparams&cols=col1,col5,co7
```

but that seems to be mixing the data to return with the query string. Should work but seems inelegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually REST results should contain all columns except big or complex properties.

- `GET /employees` returns a list of employees (possibly paged);
- `GET /employees/100` returns the employee with all columns of primitive types;
- `GET /employees/100/photo` returns big binary property `photo`;

In generally, remote services should return large objects due to network latency.

According to the standard [JSON API](https://jsonapi.org/) you can *include* related objects in the result with the `include` parameter:

`GET /employees/100?include=manager,salary`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `QueryMap` in `Retrofit` `rest` API

For Example

**In API Service**

```
 @GET("/employees")
    Call<List<Employees>> getEmployees(
        @QueryMap Map<String, String> options
    );
```

**In Activity**

```
private void getEmployees() {  
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("q", "queryparams");
    data.put("cols", "col1,col5,co7");

    // simplified call to request the news with already initialized service
    Call<List<Employees>> call = Service.getEmployees(data);
    call.enqueue(…);
}
```

Fore More Details Please Visit Retrofit Docs : [Retrofit-Rest](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-add-multiple-query-parameter-with-querymap)